I have several files in my addon. Where should I initialize the global variable?
I have several files in my addon:
__init__.py,
operators.py,
ui.py, etc.
Where should I initialize the global variable that I use in both operators.py and ui.py? And how to avoid circular import?
I can not use properties, because I only can use a global variable.
import bpy.utils.previews
some_preview = bpy.utils.previews.new()
some_preview .load("custom_icon",'some path to file\\some_icon.png', 'IMAGE')

Thank you in advance.

Hello, I think this question cannot really be answered canonically, since the answer is it depends. You can either use __init__.py or create a new file and import this file in the other ones, or another variation. What do you think you should do ?

The problem is that it always registers the classes from operator.py first (And I do not know WHY). So if I initialize a variable somewhere other than in operator.py, that variable still has the value None in operator.py. And if I initialize  it in __init__.py I have circular import.
But!!!. This time I created globals.py and it  works!!!

Yup, so you made it work ! Please be advised that it's usually not great coding practice to use global variables in your project, namely for the reasons you already encountered which are name collision and circular dependencies (and separation of concerns, debugging, concurrency, ... but that's another topic). Maybe there is another way to solve your problem. Cheers

Thanks. Unfortunately, this is currently the only way to load large image previews (import bpy.utils.previews.new() as a global variable).Maybe in the future it will change.
